# GTK: Problems redrawing widgets on Gtk.ApplicationWindow

Tags: python, gtk

I'm creating a GTK GUI in Python for an already existing program. Imagine the following structure:

```
program
|----gtk
      |-----application.py
      |-----mainwindow.py
      |-----mainwidgets.py
```

Of course this is simplified. But the GUI works somewhat like this: application.py is a Gtk.Application that creates instances of the objects in mainwidgets, provides back-end functions which are passed as callbacks to mainwindow.py, which places the widgets in a Gtk.ApplicationWindow.

There are a couple of cases where I'm having trouble. I'll go over two which I think are related.

Let's go for the simpler one first. There's a simple button defined in mainwidget, which is used as a statusbar in my program.

```
class Statusbar(Gtk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, on_button_do):
        super(Gtk.Widget, self).__init__()
        self.callback = on_button_do
        self.button_label_int = 0
        self.button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label(str(button_label_int)

    def increment_button_label(self):
        self.button_label_int += 1
        self.button.set_label(str(button_label))
```

Then, when the mainwindow receives a signal, it is instructed to call
statusbar.increment_button_label(). This crashes almost immediately with a segmentation fault, no more info given about the problem, as soon as that signal is received.

```
class AppWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    __gsignals__ = {
                "new_log": (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None, ())
                }

    def __init__(self, statusbar, sidebar, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Gtk.ApplicationWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.statusbar = statusbar
        self.sidebar = sidebar

        self.notificationBox = Gtk.Box()
        self.notificationBox.pack_start(self.statusbar.get_button(), True, True, 0)

        # MAINBOX: THE BIGGER BOX OF ALL THE LITTLE BOXES
        self.mainBox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.mainBox.pack_start(self.
        self.mainBox.pack_start(self.notificationBox, False, False, 0)

        self.add(self.mainBox)

        self.show_all()

    def do_new_log(self):
        """What should the window do when it gets a new_log signal"""
        statusbar.increment_button_label()
```

Another (related?) problem having to with updating the display of widgets: my sidebar. The sidebar is actually just a Gtk.ListStore and a Gtk.TreeView, nothing fancy. In application.py you'd find code like this:

```
def do_startup(self):

    Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)  # deep GTK magic

    self.sidebar = Sidebar(self.workspace_manager,
                           self.changeWorkspace,
                           CONF.getLastWorkspace())
```

And then that instance of sidebar is passed to mainwindow.py to be put in a box. Everything works fine for now.

The problem comes when I try to add information to the sidebar. The back-end part of it works, because if I restart the application, I can see the new entry in the sidebar. And the sidebar gets information from this backend:

```
class Sidebar(Gtk.Widget):

    def __init__(self, workspace_manager, callback_to_change_workspace, conf):
        super(Gtk.Widget, self).__init__()
        self.callback = callback_to_change_workspace
        self.ws_manager = workspace_manager
        self.lastWorkspace = conf

    def createTitle(self):
        title = Gtk.Label()
        title.set_text("Workspaces")
        return title

    def workspaceModel(self):
        self.workspace_list_info = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        for ws in self.ws_manager.getWorkspacesNames():
            treeIter = workspace_list_info.append([ws])
            if ws == self.lastWorkspace:
                self.defaultSelection = treeIter

    def workspaceView(self):
        self.lst = Gtk.TreeView(self.workspace_list_info)
        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Workspaces", renderer, text=0)
        self.lst.append_column(column)

        # select by default the last active workspace
        if self.defaultSelection is not None:
            self.selectDefault = self.lst.get_selection()
            self.selectDefault.select_iter(self.defaultSelection)

        self.selection = self.lst.get_selection()
        self.selection.connect("changed", self.callback)
```

What maindindow tries to do is put sidebar.lst into a box. That works fine. The thing is when I add a workspace via a dialog box, I doesn't show up, as I stated above.

Any idea about what could cause these problems? Is this way of organizing my problem not all right for some reason for GTK? I think the *code* itself is fine: the workspaces are added, after all, and GTK doesn't crash. It just doesn't do it fine. Also the button, at first, is displayed just fine, it even emits its signal. But as soon as I try to change its label, everything explodes.

Comment: Try to add a small self-contained to example of the problem:  it does not seem likely that the information you currently provide is enough to solve this. Also, are you using multiple threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this actually had to do with multiple threads and signals. It was solved by overriding the emit signal.

```
class _IdleObject(GObject.GObject):
"""
Override GObject.GObject to always emit signals in the main thread
by emmitting on an idle handler
"""
def __init__(self):
    GObject.GObject.__init__(self)

def emit(self, *args):
    GObject.idle_add(GObject.GObject.emit, self, *args)
```